# Vss2Git error: Illegal characters in path

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to convert an old VSS repository to Git, using the Vss2Git tool, but I am getting this error:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found out the culprit - I was manually setting PATH:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

because Git was not on the PATH by default (I had not checked that option during install).

The problem was the quotes. After I changed it to:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

it worked without any further problems.